# как реализовать прогрессбар такого типа?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-xml

Как можно реализовать прогрессбар такой нестандартной формы? Есть ли библиотеки такие?
Начало - ромбовое, а конец - обычный

[image: прогрессбар]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/Canvas

Comment: никогда не пользовался canvas'ом, всегда использовал библиотеки с гитхаба)

Comment: Тут ни одно, ни другое можно не использовать. Две картинки, серая и красная, вторая 9-patch, одна поверх другой, верхнюю тянете влево. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch

Comment: можно ли это использовать в обычном progressbar?

Comment: все, я смог это сделать. спасибо